# Как вывести сообщение после выполнения ShellExecute?

Tags: windows, delphi

Запускаю выполнение другой программы при помощи функции ShellExecute:

```
SPar := тут любая команда;
// Тут выполнения функции
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'cmd.exe', PChar(SPar), nil, SW_Hide);
```

Как показать сообщение после того как функция ShellExecute завершит свою работу?

Я предполагаю что то типа этого или как правильней будет?

```
if ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'cmd.exe', PChar(SPar), nil, SW_Hide) = ??? then
  ShowMessage('Работа завершена');
```

Comment: Вам нужно вывести сообщение после **вызова** функции или после того, как запущенная программа **завершится**?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Здравствуйте. Да именно так.

Comment: Как так? Что вам нужно?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Извините, я неправильно прочитала ваш вопрос. Нужно: после того как запущенная программа завершится...

Comment: -Подоконник должен быть вровень со стеной, или немного выступать? -Да.

Comment: @Igor, Ну само собой немного выступать... Я видать снова что то не то говорю :)?, подскажите если что не так ?

Comment: @Татьяна Я давно этого не делал. Насколько могу припомнить с `ShellExecute` такое не получится. Надо использовать `CreateProcess` и `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: @Igor, А если после вызова функции ? Возможно вывести сообщение?

Comment: Татьяна, после вызова конечно можно. В примере Вы именно так и делаете. Функция `ShellExecute` вернет значение > 32 в случае успешного выполнения. В конце условия поставьте `...SW_HIDE) > 32 then...` и попробуйте. А если необходимо дождаться завершения процесса и **потом** показать сообщение - то *Igor* верно заметил, используйте `CreateProcess`.

Comment: @Dima, Сработало, А с CreateProcess на примере завершения cmd.exe не сможете подсказать код (то есть после завершения процесса cmd.exe) ?

Comment: Ну вот же, можете нормально сформулировать вопрос, когда захотите! Ловите плюс.

Comment: @Kromster, Спасибо Вам и главное не думайте - что я, к Вам, как то злостно настроена. Все мы люди и я уважаю мнение каждого, в том числе и ваше. Приятного рабочего дня.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ - никак.

Функция `ShellExecute` не позволяет получить информацию о времени жизни программы. Данная функция является устаревшей и не [рекомендуется](https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2015/01/never-use-ShellExecute.html) к использованию.

Вам нужно вызвать функцию `ShelExecuteEx` или `CreateProcess` (в данном конкретном случае [лучше](https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2015/01/avoid-using-ShellExecuteEx.html) последнюю), получить хендл запущенного процесса и дождаться завершения этого процесса при помощи функции `WaitForSingleObject`

```
var
  LCmd: string;
  LInfo: TStartupInfo;
  LPI: TProcessInformation;
begin
  // Заполняем структуры
  LCmd := 'cmd.exe ' + SPar;
  FillChar(LInfo, SizeOf(LInfo), 0);
  LInfo.cb := SizeOf(LInfo);
  LInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  LInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  // Запускаем программу
  Win32Check(CreateProcess(
    'cmd.exe',        // lpApplicationName,
    PChar(LCmd),      // lpCommandLine,
    nil,              // lpProcessAttributes,
    nil,              // lpThreadAttributes,
    False,            // bInheritHandles,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, // dwCreationFlags,
    nil,              // lpEnvironment,
    nil,              // lpCurrentDirectory,
    LInfo,            // lpStartupInfo,
    LPI               // lpProcessInformation
  ));
  try
    // Закрываем хендл главного потока (он нам не нужен)
    CloseHandle(LPI.hThread);
    // Ждем завершения процесса
    Win32Check(WaitForSingleObject(LPI.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_FAILED);
  finally
    // Закрываем хендл процесса
    CloseHandle(LPI.hProcess);
  end;
  ShowMessage('Программа завершена');
end;
```

Comment: Интересный код, сейчас обязательно изучу. Многое что и понятно, мне, как не опытной а многое и нет. То есть по сути все мои параметры можно переписать под ваш код и тот код что в теме не использовать, правильно я поняла ?

Comment: @Татьяна Именно так. Про функцию `ShellExecute` забудьте вообще, а `ShellExecuteEx` используйте только тогда, когда вам нужно открыть документ зарегистрированной программой

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov, Вы, как всегда, приятно удивляете, за что Вам огромнейшее спасибо. Сейчас каждое слово в вашем коде разберу и буду изучать.

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov, При запуске вот такое код выдает - system error code 2 не удается найти указанный файл. Это имеется в виду файл cmd.exe или ?..

Comment: @Татьяна Скорее всего нужно указать полный путь к `cmd.exe`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, указала, работает. Последний вопрос, а как то глобально авто-определение cmd.exe задать нельзя ? Я спрашиваю потому что в ShellExecute стояло просто 'cmd.exe' и все.

Comment: ShellExecute отдает команду на запуск проводнику. А тот ищет ее по всем каталогам из переменной `%PATH%` CreateProcess так не умеет. Либо сами ищите cmd.exe по всем каталогам, указанных в %PATH% либо берите имя из переменной `%COMSPEC%`

Comment: А еще такой вопрос по вашему коду: Как сделать что бы окно программы Delphi в процессе выполнения CMD.exe не застывало. А то сейчас окно просто замораживаться и только после окончания работы его можно двигать.

Comment: @Татьяна Так вы же сами просили дождаться завершения программы. Чтобы не застывало, нужно ждать в отдельном потоке

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, я знаю, просто до сих пор играюсь с разными настройками - этого кода.И интересно как сделать в отдельном потоке. Ну это если есть возможность ? А так, я, в эту тему, начинаю вникать -углубленно.

Comment: @Татьяна Учитывая то, что данный вопрос кардинально отличается от исходного, рекомендую создать еще один вопрос

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, Создала новую тему по этому коду.